# What has to be done to show a marquee output with a scroll menu?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

Today i continue my work, Building a menu with a vb.net console application. I found more samples to build with Windows forms. Still i try to get Basic Knowledge with the console surface.I was not able to put the following marquee text in a scroll menu, the second Code past the marquee text.

```
Module Module1

Dim aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer
Const marqueeText As String = "The quick brown fox...   "
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim direction As Boolean = False

Sub Main()
    aTimer.AutoReset = True
    aTimer.Interval = 100 '1/10 second
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf tick
    aTimer.Start()
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Private Sub tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Console.Clear()

    If sb.Length = 0 Then sb.Append(marqueeText)
    If direction Then
        sb.Insert(0, sb(sb.Length - 1))
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1)
    Else
        sb.Append(sb(0))
        sb.Remove(0, 1)
    End If

    Console.CursorLeft = 10 'no visible change
    Console.CursorTop = 10 'visible change
    Console.Write("{0}{1}", vbCr, sb.ToString)
End Sub

End Module
```

The marquee text Output from above is not easy to manage with the     console.cursorleft command. I have no clue how to move it to the right or to put the marquee Output in the following Code, a scroll menu, on the third line.

```
Module Module1

Dim MenuList As New List(Of String)

Sub PrintMenu(highlight As Integer, left As Integer, top As Integer)

    Dim Nickvektor() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    For I = 0 To MenuList.Count - 1

        Console.CursorLeft = left
        Console.CursorTop = top + I

        If I = highlight Then
            Console.Write("{0}", "[" & Nickvektor(I) & "]")
        Else
            Console.Write(MenuList(I))
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub Main()

    Console.CursorVisible = False

    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim Nickvektor() As String = {"   "}

    For counter As Integer = 0 To 0

        Do

            For Each s In Nickvektor
                MenuList.Add(s)
            Next

            x += 1
        Loop Until x = 5

    Next

    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 16)
    Console.Write("[ ]")
    Dim CurrentItem As Integer = 0
    Dim CurrentKey As ConsoleKey
    While CurrentKey <> ConsoleKey.Enter

        PrintMenu(CurrentItem, 10, 10)

        CurrentKey = Console.ReadKey(True).Key
        Select Case CurrentKey

            Case ConsoleKey.DownArrow
                CurrentItem += 1

            Case ConsoleKey.UpArrow
                CurrentItem -= 1

        End Select

        CurrentItem = (CurrentItem + MenuList.Count) Mod MenuList.Count
    End While

End Sub

End Module
```

The menu Frame for the above Code can be used with the up and down arrows on the Keyboard.
Maybe it is to much work but i have no clue how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Solution for the marquee Output is an easy change of the original code. The wrap, vbCr, was the main Problem to move the text output toward  the right edge oft he screen. The following code can be used to change the cursorTop Positon and also the cursorLeft Position of the Text.

```
    Console.CursorVisible = False
    Console.CursorLeft = 30
    Console.CursorTop = 10
    Console.Write("{0}", sb.ToString)
```

The heavy part are the  Menu code Lines. To answer my own question some additional help was necessary.
[I posted my question on the MS developer Network written in german language. With the following link it can be viewed.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/8ea15b1e-235d-42d5-8dfa-f6d2e711c1a8/wie-kann-ich-die-ausgabe-eines-tick-events-einer-konsolenanwendung-nach-rechts-verschieben-und-in?forum=visualbasicde)

For the case the link should be broken or other cases i post the code on this site.

```
Module Module1
Dim MenuList As New List(Of String)

Dim aTimer As New System.Timers.Timer
Const marqueeText As String = "The quick brown fox...   "
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim direction As Boolean = False

Sub PrintMenu(highlight As Integer, left As Integer, top As Integer)
    Dim Nickvektor() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    For I = 0 To MenuList.Count - 1
        Console.CursorLeft = left
        Console.CursorTop = top + I
        If I = highlight Then
            Console.Write("{0}", "[" & Nickvektor(I) & "]")
        Else
            Console.Write(MenuList(I))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Console.CursorVisible = False
    aTimer.AutoReset = True
    aTimer.Interval = 100 '1/10 second
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf tick
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim Nickvektor() As String = {"   "}
    For counter As Integer = 0 To 0
        Do
            For Each s In Nickvektor
                MenuList.Add(s)
            Next
            x += 1
        Loop Until x = 5
    Next
    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 16)
    Console.Write("[ ]")
    Dim CurrentItem As Integer = 0
    Dim CurrentKey As ConsoleKey
    While CurrentKey <> ConsoleKey.Enter

        If CurrentItem = 2 Then ' Zero can be used to show the marquee output prompt
            aTimer.Start()  ' With a change to two or four the timer can be stoped:
            'Else
            'If aTimer.Enabled Then
            '    aTimer.Stop()
            'End If
        End If

        PrintMenu(CurrentItem, 10, 10)
        CurrentKey = Console.ReadKey(True).Key
        Select Case CurrentKey
            Case ConsoleKey.DownArrow
                CurrentItem += 1
            Case ConsoleKey.UpArrow
                CurrentItem -= 1
        End Select
        CurrentItem = (CurrentItem + MenuList.Count) Mod MenuList.Count
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    If sb.Length = 0 Then sb.Append(marqueeText)
    If direction Then
        sb.Insert(0, sb(sb.Length - 1))
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1)
    Else
        sb.Append(sb(0))
        sb.Remove(0, 1)
    End If
    Console.CursorVisible = False
    Console.CursorLeft = 20
    Console.CursorTop = 12      ' For the first Element CursorTop=10, fort he third 12
    Console.Write("{0}", sb.ToString)
End Sub
End Module
```

To learn an other language like English i have to search a lot. Visual Basic Code is mostly written with English key words for the commands. I think it is easier to look up the maintainable changes for your self. To search is not every day funny.